# Why does this HTML/JS revert back to the original after changing the inner HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am starting to learn JavaScript and I was wondering why this doesn't permanently make "Ephemeral" appear before the button and why it reverts back to the original HTML page before the button is pressed?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mind.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id = "identifier"></h1>
    <form>
        <button value = "button!" onclick="doSomething()"> </button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**mind.js**

```
function doSomething() {
    document.getElementById("identifier").innerHTML = '<i>Ephemeral</i>';
}
```

Comment: who added syntax highlighting????

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you're submitting the form, which is refreshing the page. Add `return false` to the inline handler, if you don't want to submit yet.

```
<button value = "button!" onclick="doSomething(); return false;"> </button>
```

---

Or add `return` before the call, and add `return false` to the function.

```
<button value = "button!" onclick="return doSomething();"> </button>
```

```
function doSomething() {
    document.getElementById("identifier").innerHTML = '<i>Ephemeral</i>';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Better yet, just take the form tags out completely. I don't see the point of them being there in the first place.

Comment: @David: Yeah, true. I'm assuming OP has an eventual purpose for the `form` though.

Comment: @David Thumbs up as I was beating my head against the all on a similar issue.